# Every time I clean, run, or build the project, the manifest file gets reloaded from disc

Tags: android, android-studio

This is a brand new project.  All i've done is add

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and Set the icon, but i incorrectly set the icon path initially. Now whenever I try to run, clean, build, or sync the project, it reverts to the initial, incorrect file.  I can delete its entire contents, and it still gets replaced.

I know it's reloading from disc because when I ctrl-z it asks if I want to undo reload from disc

I've tried invalidating the cache and restarting, but nothing has worked so far.

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something very basic?

edit: Android Studio 1.4

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the correct file? If it's the manifest in the `/build` folder you're editing, that's why that's happening. Make sure to edit the one under the `/src` folder.

Comment: hrm.  good question.  I didn't think to look.  I'm in the process of updating to 1.5.  i'll check when It's done

Comment: Yup. that was the problem :)  I imagine some philospher once said something wise about looking in the wrong place.  thanks